# Box shadow on right border of polygon shape?

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in adding a box shadow to the right border of a polygon shape just like the image below:

[image]

and I want to add shadow where the red line is as you can see it in the image below:

[image]

and I made this shape simple by this:

HTML:

```
<div class="shape">
   ....          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shape {
   background: url(img/1.jpg);
   border-top: 400px solid transparent;
   border-right: 40px solid #ffffff;
}
```

I did not used *clip-path*, since it is not compatible with IE and you have to do some extra settings to make it work on *Firefox* and some other browsers and I wanted to keep it simple so I went with the easy way. But the problem i am facing is to add shadow to the right corner only using *CSS*. Is there any solution for that? or I will have to use *clip-path* in order to add shadow to right corner?

Comment: *compatible with IE* ... How many IEs you want to support?

Comment: IE9, 10 and 11 @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Well the main issue here is that you're using a *jpg* which is a format that doesn't support transparency. Therefore, if you try to render an image with transparency using the JPEG format, the white space that you _think_ is transparent, is actually just filled with the color white. If you re-render the image on a PNG format and use a `drop-shadow` filter you should get the effect you want.

Comment: Yea but image is in jpeg format and if it is about png format then why don't i simply crop the image in polygon shape and add simple box shadow. But I want to handle it throught proper css so that if teh image is in square shape it should display as polygon @CristianHG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can afford that the image is slightly rotated... (4 degrees)

```css
.rightDiagonal{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-right:35px;
}

.rightDiagonal img{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(4deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
  
  margin:-15px;
  box-shadow: 16px 0 25px -20px rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="rightDiagonal">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x180/0ba">  
</div>
```

#### otherwise...

if not, than you'll need an additional layer (`<div>`) of complexity, where the most outer div is the wrapper, the inner div has the shadow and is at `4deg` degrees and than the inner image if restored to 0 using `-4deg`

```css
.rightDiagonal{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-right:15px;
}
.rightDiagonal div {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: -15px 0 -15px -15px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(4deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
  box-shadow: 16px 0 25px -20px rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}
.rightDiagonal img{
  margin-right: -15px;
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rightDiagonal">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x180/0ba"></div>
</div>


<div class="rightDiagonal">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/170x200/a0b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your solution is what i want but the image should not rotate. Can you please show a snippet that applies to your second solution?

Comment: @Rafiquekj sure. Done.

Answer (score -2):

Try this CSS:

```
#shadow-div{
    margin-right:20px; /* Set to 0 if you don't want shadow at the right side */
    margin-left:0px; /* Set to 20px if you want shadow at the left side */
    margin-top:0px; /* Set to 20px if you want shadow at the top side */
    margin-bottom:0px; /* Set to 20px if you want shadow at the bottom side */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black; 
    background: url(img/1.jpg);
    border-top: 400px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show a snippet that applies to this *solution*?

Comment: @Nikola, this won't work correctly on his case as you're using a `box-shadow`, which will (_inferred by its name_) have a _box_ shape and not a custom slanted shape like he wants it

Comment: Exactly @CristianHG